# Python: convert string column to a date time column ('%d/%m/%YT%H:%M:%S')

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert a string column in a pandas dataframe to a date time column. The elements in the string column look like '1/07/2020T10:10:00'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":['1/07/2020T10:10:00', '1/08/2020T10:10:00', '1/09/2020T10:10:00']})
print(df)
                 date
0  1/07/2020T10:10:00
1  1/08/2020T10:10:00
2  1/09/2020T10:10:00
```

Comment: don't use format at all

Comment: @AnuragDabas doesn't quite work because it infers `1` as month (while from format it looks like it's supposed to be day). The problem is datetime formats don't do non-zero padded days (unless you make your own format). Also, the year format is wrong (should be `%Y`)

Comment: @dm2 that's  why pd.to_datetime has a kwarg "dayfirst" which you can set to True in this case.

Comment: check out documentation, "Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number." basically your day if a single digit needs to have 0 before it.

Comment: @MrFuppes that is great point that I managed to forget, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

### Sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":['1/07/2020T10:10:00', '1/08/2020T10:10:00', '1/09/2020T10:10:00']})
print(df)
                 date
0  1/07/2020T10:10:00
1  1/08/2020T10:10:00
2  1/09/2020T10:10:00
```

### Solution:

First, you need to convert the Dated to Datetime ..

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df)
                 date
0 2020-01-07 10:10:00
1 2020-01-08 10:10:00
2 2020-01-09 10:10:00
```

now use `dt.strftime` to get your choice ..

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%YT%H:%M:%S'))
print(df)
                 date
0 2020-07-01 10:10:00
1 2020-08-01 10:10:00
2 2020-09-01 10:10:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the year is with century, it should be `%Y` not `%y`.